# How to escape single quotes in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

This is a very basic quesiton about Doctrine. How are single quotes escaped?

For example, title needs to be escaped as it contains a single quote:

```
    $query = $this->entityManager->
            createQuery("SELECT p  from \RTH\Entity\Prod p
                         JOIN p.prodns ps
                         JOIN ps.events e
                         WHERE p.title = '" . $title . "'");
```

Is there a specific way to do this in Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using prepared statements 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements

Comment: I just want to know how to escape single quotes, I don't really want to change how things work. Is there no options for simple escaping in Doctrine?

Comment: If the purpose is to escape something for a query, always use prepared statements. Doing anything else is just an invitation for SQL injection.

Comment: I guess I'll go with prepared statements then. I got a good explanation from a user named `zomg` on the #doctrine IRC channel.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements is really the way to go, but if you can't upgrade your code, you could use the `quote` method of the Doctrine\DBAL\Connection object.

As per your code, I think you could access the connection object doing:
`$this->getConnection()`

See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.12/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#quote