# How do you escape ' on doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

How do you escape ' on doctrine?

I made this code

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
                "SELECT a FROM AcmeTopBundle:ArtData a WHERE
                a.name = '". mysql_escape_string($name) ."'");
```

but when the  $name is A'z

it returns error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]          
SELECT a FROM AcmeTopBundle:ArtData a WHERE  
                a.name = 'A\'s'
```

I think I escaped by `mysql_escape_string` in case of using raw sql.

How can I avoid this error on doctrine?

Comment: With DBAL : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/security.html#right-quoting-escaping-values

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is using parameters and querybuilder (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html)...

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder(
            "SELECT a FROM AcmeTopBundle:ArtData a WHERE
            a.name = :name")
     ->setParameter('name',$name);
$result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, even though there is accepted answer it is not for question as it is in title.
@Sven's answer comes close, but fails to mention:

[Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/security.html)

> To escape user input in those scenarios use the Connection#quote() method.

And I have a gripe with "scenarios", or more with people pushing prepared statements like some holy grail. Well they are nice in theory, in practice at least in PHP they are quite shity, as they are unable to do simple stuff like `IN (<list>)` or multi inserts with `VALUES (<bla bla>), (<more stuff>)` which is a huge ass deal, as without it one ends up resorting to quite sub-optimal SQL (to put it lightly) quite commonly (well if one religiously insist on prepared statements at least).

Comment: Please note (from the Doctrine docs linked in the answer): Connection#quote “is only available for SQL, not for DQL. For DQL you are always encouraged to use prepared statements not only for security, but also for caching reasons”. :-(

Answer (score 5):

This does not answer your question, but explains what's wrong with your code. It didn't fit into a comment.

You cannot and should not use `mysql_escape_string()`

- It is the wrong escape function, the right one used to be `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Reading [the documentation](http://pt2.php.net/mysql-escape-string) does not sound like it, but to properly escape, you have to know which character encoding is being used. In western encoding schemes like ASCII, ISO-8859-x or even UTF-8 it probably does not make a difference, but there are some exotic chinese encodings around which absolutely need to know whether that `"` byte belongs to another byte, or comes on it's own.
- When using mysql_real_escape_string(), you need to have an already open DB connection created with mysql_connect(). If you don't, PHP tries to open a new connection with default user and password as defined in the php.ini file. This usually results in an error because without password the database won't let you do anything. And additionally, if you have success, then the encoding setting of this connection most likely is not the one used by Doctrine.
- Using any of the mysql_* functions is wrong, because these are deprecated. The correct way would be to use mysqli_* functions.
- Doctrine may use any of the three database connection methods: mysql, mysqli or PDO. You have to choose the one really being used if you want to manually call the correct escaping function. While the connection is already created. And somehow you need to grab that connection resource to allow the function you are calling to detect the used encoding.

So in the end there are plenty of reasons why it is wrong to just use any escaping that sound like it is doing the job.

The right way is to use the escaping of the database layer you are using. If you use Doctrine, the use it for escaping. Or better, avoid escaping, use prepared statements or the query builder and let Doctrine deal with the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13377430/829533

you can use prepared statements http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements

*From the documentation:*

```
$date = new \DateTime("2011-03-05 14:00:21");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE publish_date > ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $date, "datetime");
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show how to insert the data into the database where you would normally have to use real_escape_string.

Doctrine and Symfony 3 using prepared not QueryBuilder:

```
// get the post value
$value = $request->request->get('value'); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name`
(`column_name1`,`column_name2`)
VALUES
('Static Data',?)
";

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue(1, $value);
$result->execute();
```

Now for a bonus to get a success/fail if you are using auto increment records:

```
$id = $em->getConnection()->lastInsertId();
```

if $id has a value then it executed the insert. If it does not the insert failed.